# Excel VBA - Add contents of cell into first space of file name

Tags: excel, vba

On Excel spreadsheet, I have a path to folder in A3, file names from A3 folder listed in A6 down. When I click in J column existing macro generates an email with attached file from active row. I need to add to this macro a portion of code which will also rename that file by adding contents of K1 into first space into file name, i.e. to rename "First Second.pdf" to "First contents of K1 Second.pdf" or "First Second Third.pdf" to "First contents of K1 Second Third.pdf"

```
Sub Email_with_attachment()


Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    '------------------------
        Signature = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\"
    If Dir(Signature, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
        Signature = Signature & Dir$(Signature & "*.htm")
    Else:
        Signature = ""
    End If
    Signature = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(Signature).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2).ReadAll

    '------------------------
    olMail.To = ""
    olMail.CC = ""
    olMail.VotingOptions = "Buyer resolving with Supplier;Now received/Corrected"
    olMail.Importance = olImportanceHigh
    '
    olMail.FlagRequest = "Reply"
    olMail.FlagDueBy = Range("H1").Value
'    olMail.OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested = True
'    olMail.ReadReceiptRequested = True
    '
    olMail.Subject = "Invoice issue: " & Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value
    olMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML

    olMail.HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Hello, <br /><br />Should this have been received by now?<br /><br /> Use Voting buttons above to reply, for convenience. </BODY></HTML>" & Signature


    olMail.Attachments.Add Range("A3") & Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value
    olMail.Display

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just before your `Attachments.Add` line, you need to rename the file.  So you could do something like this:

```
OldFilename = Range("A3") & Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row))
NewFilename = Range("A3") & Mid(Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)), 1, 6) & Range("K1") & " " & Mid(Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)), 7)

Name OldFilename As NewFilename
olMail.Attachments.Add NewFilename
```

Comment: Why is the `Range.Value` member call explicit only in the last instance, and implicit in every other? (edit: just noticed OP's code had the same)

Comment: The objective is to rename "First Second.pdf"  to  "First contents of K1 Second.pdf"  or "First Second Third.pdf"  to  "First contents of K1 Second Third.pdf"

Comment: @Brian M Stafford - The objective is to rename "First Second.pdf" to "First contents of K1 Second.pdf" or "First Second Third.pdf" to "First contents of K1 Second Third.pdf"

Comment: @Brian M Stafford - yes, however the objective is different than what the updated code does.  Contents of K1 need to go into first space within file name, i.e. objective is to rename "First Second.pdf" to "First contents of K1 Second.pdf" or "First Second Third.pdf" to "First contents of K1 Second Third.pdf"

Comment: @Alex try my latest update.  It factors in the fact that the filename contains a path.